# How to show attribution above Bing max zoom level where allow tile image stretching?

Tags: mapbox, mapping, mapbox-gl-js, bing-maps

Currently some of location Bing provide image for stretch after crossing max zoom level 21 as per Bing metadata. Wanted to show attribution above max level where Bing tiles able to stretch it out. My current doesn't allow me to do the same. Code is similar like mention it here https://gist.github.com/pagameba/1221998#file-tilelayer-bing-js-L116

```
var metadata = this.metadata;
      var res = metadata.resourceSets[0].resources[0];
      var bounds = this._map.getBounds();
      var providers = res.imageryProviders, zoom = this._map.getZoom() + 1,
          copyrights = "", provider, i, ii, j, jj, bbox, coverage;
      for (i=0,ii=providers.length; i<ii; ++i) {
          provider = providers[i];
          for (j=0,jj=provider.coverageAreas.length; j<jj; ++j) {
              coverage = provider.coverageAreas[j];
              if (zoom <= coverage.zoomMax && zoom >= coverage.zoomMin && coverage.bbox.intersects(bounds)) {
                  copyrights += provider.attribution + " ";
                  j = jj;
              }
          }
      }
      this._map.attributionControl.removeAttribution(this.attribution);
      this._map.attributionControl._attributions = {};
      this._map.attributionControl._update();
      this.attribution = this.attributionTemplate
        .replace('{logo}', metadata.brandLogoUri)
        .replace('{copyrights}', copyrights);
      this._map.attributionControl.addAttribution(this.attribution);
    }
```